# Apple rejected my application because of Flurry

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, flurry

My application is rejected today by apple.

Their note is this:

---

During our extended review we found that the app does in fact send the user's MAC address via the Flurry SDK.

Sending the user's hardware identifier is not appropriate, and requires this feature to be removed to be considered for PLA 3.3.9 compliance. Please revise the binary to not send the MAC address, then resubmit for review.

---

So I added Flurry's Privacy Policy url (https://info.yahoo.com/privacy/us/yahoo/) into my application privacy policy url in iTunes connect. And then they replied this:

---

Thank you for your patience during extended review. Any app that sends the user's MAC address without their previous knowledge is an issue with PLA 3.3.9. In this app's case Flurry collects the user's MAC address, and sends it to third parties.

To be considered for compliance with PLA 3.3.9 it would be appropriate to either:

- Remove the functionality that sends the user's MAC address

or

- Add a statement to your privacy policy in iTunes Connect, and include statements in the binary (requires a resubmission of the binary) that explicitly tells users where and how their device identifier MAC address is being sent, and how it's being used.

We look forward to your resubmission once either change has been made.

Thank you,
App Store Review

---

What can I do now ? Any suggestion ? I dont want to revise my binary. There is tons of application that uses flurry's sdk and there is no result on google about this issue. I dont think they rejected all applications which uses flurry.

Comment: Just to be sure, which flurry SDK version was it. Was it 5.4 as the answer below suggests?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Flurry release notes, MAC address was removed for iOS7+ as of 5.3.0 (Aug 20 2014): http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/Code/ReleaseNotes

It sounds like they may have only partially removed it prior to that, as in a post from Sept 17 2013 they claimed to have already removed it: http://www.flurry.com/updates/bid/100883/Flurry-Support-for-iOS-7-and-iPhone-5S#.VGE-WlnF80o

Comment: So do you think it's possible an app could be rejected if it was supporting iOS 6 , because then maybe Flurry SDK 5.4 does try to access the MAC address?