# iOS app rejection due to Flurry sending Mac address?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, flurry, flurry-analytics

My app was rejected by apple and the rejection notice says my app uses Flurry to send the mac address. From my research, this had been removed from Flurry for iOS 7+ according to this:

http://www.flurry.com/updates/bid/100883/Flurry-Support-for-iOS-7-and-iPhone-5S#.VVZ7Hcbuekh

I am targeting iOS 8 onwards. After talking to app review team, I received the following:

> PLA 3.3.9
>
> We found your app sends the user's MAC address via the Flurry SDK (http://data.flurry.com/aas.do). This can be seen in the "Request" which has the SHA1 Hash of the MAC Address "02:00:00:00:00:00." We have attached a screenshot of the specific request.

They attached this screenshot which I can't make any sense of. Looks like a screenshot from wireshark or some network sniffer.

[image]

How should I go about fixing this as Flurry is a closed SDK?

Comment: This is interesting because this is a "soft" MAC address and only the hash is being sent. Apple must be looking for the hashes or a few "soft"MAC addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that contacting Flurry support about this issue would seem the simplest option. Include the info from the Apple reviewer and see what they say. I would have thought this issue would also affect any other Flurry users, but possibly the Apple reviewers have only just started looking for the hash.

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted Flurry Today.
From [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683879/apple-rejected-my-application-because-of-flurry) it looks like Flurry removed it from version 5.3.0